# Linphone Android not receiving calls

Tags: android, voip, linphone

Recently I have been creating a new Android app to make/receive VoIP calls using Linphone lib. The first version of the app worked almost ok, I updated the lib and decided to do some code arrange, and for some reason, the app does not longer receive calls.

All the VoIP functionality is inside an android service:

```
package com.test.voice.linphone;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.test.voice.voice.R;

import org.linphone.core.AVPFMode;
import org.linphone.core.Address;
import org.linphone.core.AuthInfo;
import org.linphone.core.AuthMethod;
import org.linphone.core.Call;
import org.linphone.core.CallLog;
import org.linphone.core.CallStats;
import org.linphone.core.ChatMessage;
import org.linphone.core.ChatRoom;
import org.linphone.core.ConfiguringState;
import org.linphone.core.Content;
import org.linphone.core.Core;
import org.linphone.core.CoreException;
import org.linphone.core.CoreListener;
import org.linphone.core.EcCalibratorStatus;
import org.linphone.core.Event;
import org.linphone.core.Factory;
import org.linphone.core.Friend;
import org.linphone.core.FriendList;
import org.linphone.core.GlobalState;
import org.linphone.core.InfoMessage;
import org.linphone.core.PayloadType;
import org.linphone.core.PresenceModel;
import org.linphone.core.ProxyConfig;
import org.linphone.core.PublishState;
import org.linphone.core.Reason;
import org.linphone.core.RegistrationState;
import org.linphone.core.SubscriptionState;
import org.linphone.core.Transports;
import org.linphone.core.VersionUpdateCheckResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class LinphoneService extends Service {

    // *************************************** CONSTANTS *************************************** //

    private static final String TAG = "linphone_service";
    private static final String WAKE_LOG_TAG = ":voicewakelock";

    private static final String LIN_TAG = "libcore";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "VoiceAgent";

    private static final long TIME_ITERATE = 200;

    // ****************************************** VARS ***************************************** //

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private Core mCore;
    private String mLpConfig = null;
    private String mConfigFactoryFile = null;
    public String mLinphoneConfigFile = null;
    private String mRootCaFile = null;
    private String mRingSoundFile = null;
    private String mRingBackSoundFile = null;
    private String mPauseSoundFile = null;
    private AuthInfo mAuthInfo;
    private ProxyConfig mProxyConfig;
    private Timer mIterateTimer;
    private LinphoneCallback mCallback;
    private RegistrationState mRegistrationState = RegistrationState.None;

    // ************************************* INNER CLASSES ************************************* //

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LinphoneService getService() {
            return LinphoneService.this;
        }
    }

    // *************************************** LIFECYCLE *************************************** //

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKE_LOG_TAG);
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        String basePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        mLpConfig = basePath + "/lpconfig.xsd";
        mConfigFactoryFile = basePath + "/linphonerc";
        mLinphoneConfigFile = basePath + "/.linphonerc";
        mRootCaFile = basePath + "/rootca.pem";
        mRingSoundFile = basePath + "/oldphone_mono.wav";
        mRingBackSoundFile = basePath + "/ringback.wav";
        mPauseSoundFile = basePath + "/toy_mono.wav";
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWakeLock.release();

        cancelIterateTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // ************************************* PUBLIC METHODS ************************************ //

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * Set a {@link LinphoneCallback} to receive event callbacks.
     *
     * @param callback {@link LinphoneCallback} to set.
     */
    public void setCallback(LinphoneCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Initiate Linphone library, set configuration.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void initLibrary() throws Exception {

        copyAssetsFromPackage();

        Factory.instance().setDebugMode(true, LIN_TAG);
        mCore = Factory.instance().createCore(
                mLinphoneConfigFile, mConfigFactoryFile, this);
        mCore.addListener(getCoreListener());
        mCore.enableIpv6(false);
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        mCore.setUserAgent(USER_AGENT, packageInfo.versionName);
        mCore.setRemoteRingbackTone(mRingSoundFile);
        mCore.setRing(mRingSoundFile);
        mCore.setRootCa(mRootCaFile);
        mCore.setPlayFile(mPauseSoundFile);
        mCore.setNetworkReachable(true);
        mCore.enableEchoCancellation(true);
        mCore.enableEchoLimiter(true);
        mCore.enableAdaptiveRateControl(true);
        mCore.clearAllAuthInfo();
        mCore.clearProxyConfig();

        enablePayloads();

        startIterateTimer();

    }

    /**
     * Login agains the VoIP server.
     *
     * @param name     Username.
     * @param password Password.
     * @param host     Server.
     * @param tcpPort  Specify the TCP port to use, only TCP available.
     * @throws CoreException
     */
    public void login(String name, String password, String host, int tcpPort)
            throws CoreException {

        String identity = "sip:" + name + "@" + host;
        String proxy = "sip:" + host;

        Address proxyAddress = Factory.instance().createAddress(proxy);
        Address identityAddress = Factory.instance().createAddress(identity);
        if (proxyAddress == null || identityAddress == null) {
            throw new CoreException("Proxy or Identity address is null.");
        }

        mProxyConfig = mCore.createProxyConfig();
        mProxyConfig.setIdentityAddress(identityAddress);
        mProxyConfig.setServerAddr(proxyAddress.asStringUriOnly());
        mProxyConfig.setAvpfMode(AVPFMode.Disabled);
        mProxyConfig.setAvpfRrInterval(0);
        mProxyConfig.enableQualityReporting(false);
        mProxyConfig.setQualityReportingCollector(null);
        mProxyConfig.setQualityReportingInterval(0);
        //        mProxyConfig.setRoute(proxyAddress.asStringUriOnly());
        mProxyConfig.enableRegister(true);

        mAuthInfo = Factory.instance().createAuthInfo(
                name, null, password, null, null, host);

        Transports transports = mCore.getTransports();
        transports.setUdpPort(-1);
        transports.setTlsPort(-1);
        transports.setTcpPort(tcpPort);
        mCore.setTransports(transports);

        mCore.addProxyConfig(mProxyConfig);
        mCore.addAuthInfo(mAuthInfo);
        mCore.setDefaultProxyConfig(mProxyConfig);

    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from remote VoIP server.
     */
    public void logout() {
        if (mProxyConfig != null) {
            mProxyConfig.edit();
            mProxyConfig.enableRegister(false);
            mProxyConfig.done();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accept incoming call.
     */
    public void acceptCall() {
        mCore.acceptCall(mCore.getCurrentCall());
    }

    /**
     * Decline current call.
     */
    public void declineCall() {
        mCore.declineCall(mCore.getCurrentCall(), Reason.Declined);
    }

    /**
     * Hang up the current call.
     */
    public void hangUp() {
        Call currentCall = mCore.getCurrentCall();
        if (currentCall != null) {
            mCore.terminateCall(currentCall);
        } else if (mCore.isInConference()) {
            mCore.terminateConference();
        } else {
            mCore.terminateAllCalls();
        }
    }

    // ************************************ PRIVATE METHODS ************************************ //

    /**
     * Copy resource files.
     *
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurrs.
     */
    private void copyAssetsFromPackage() throws IOException {
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.oldphone_mono, mRingSoundFile);
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.ringback, mRingBackSoundFile);
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.toy_mono, mPauseSoundFile);
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.linphonerc_default, mLinphoneConfigFile);
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.linphonerc_factory, (
                new File(this.mConfigFactoryFile)).getName());
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.lpconfig, mLpConfig);
        copyIfNotExist(this, R.raw.rootca, mRootCaFile);
    }

    private void copyIfNotExist(Context context, int resourceId, String target) throws IOException {
        File fileToCopy = new File(target);
        if (!fileToCopy.exists()) {
            copyFromPackage(context, resourceId, fileToCopy.getName());
        }
    }

    private void copyFromPackage(Context context, int resourceId, String target) throws
            IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(target, 0);
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        byte[] buff = new byte[8048];

        int readByte;
        while ((readByte = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, readByte);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

    /**
     * Get the {@link CoreListener}.
     *
     * @return Instance of {@link CoreListener}.
     */
    private CoreListener getCoreListener() {
        return new CoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalStateChanged(Core core, GlobalState globalState, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - Global State Changed: " + s);
                mCallback.onGlobalStateChanged(globalState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationStateChanged(Core core, ProxyConfig proxyConfig,
                                                   RegistrationState registrationState,
                                                   String state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Registration State Changed: " +
                        state);
                if (registrationState != mRegistrationState) {
                    mCallback.onRegistrationStateChanged(registrationState);
                }
                mRegistrationState = registrationState;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(Core core, Call call, Call.State state, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Call State Changed");
                mCallback.onCallStateChanged(call, state);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotifyPresenceReceived(Core core, Friend friend) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Notify Presence Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotifyPresenceReceivedForUriOrTel(Core core, Friend friend, String s,
                                                            PresenceModel presenceModel) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Notify Presence Received For Uri Or Tel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNewSubscriptionRequested(Core core, Friend friend, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On New Subscription Requested");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationRequested(Core core, AuthInfo authInfo, AuthMethod
                    authMethod) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Authentication Requested");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallLogUpdated(Core core, CallLog callLog) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Call Log Updated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(Core core, ChatRoom chatRoom, ChatMessage chatMessage) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Message Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceivedUnableDecrypt(Core core, ChatRoom chatRoom, ChatMessage
                    chatMessage) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Message Received Unable Decrypt");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIsComposingReceived(Core core, ChatRoom chatRoom) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Is Composing Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDtmfReceived(Core core, Call call, int i) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Dtmf Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onReferReceived(Core core, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Refer Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEncryptionChanged(Core core, Call call, boolean b, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Call Encrypted Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransferStateChanged(Core core, Call call, Call.State state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Transfer State Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBuddyInfoUpdated(Core core, Friend friend) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Buddy Info Updated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallStatsUpdated(Core core, Call call, CallStats callStats) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Call Stats Updated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInfoReceived(Core core, Call call, InfoMessage infoMessage) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Info Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubscriptionStateChanged(Core core, Event event, SubscriptionState
                    subscriptionState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Subscription State Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNotifyReceived(Core core, Event event, String s, Content content) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Notify Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubscribeReceived(Core core, Event event, String s, Content content) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Subscribe Received");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPublishStateChanged(Core core, Event event, PublishState publishState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Publish State Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfiguringStatus(Core core, ConfiguringState configuringState, String
                    s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Configuring Status");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkReachable(Core core, boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Network Reachable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLogCollectionUploadStateChanged(Core core, Core
                    .LogCollectionUploadState logCollectionUploadState, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Log Collection Upload StateChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLogCollectionUploadProgressIndication(Core core, int i, int i1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Log Collection Upload ProgressIndication");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFriendListCreated(Core core, FriendList friendList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Friend List Created");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFriendListRemoved(Core core, FriendList friendList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Friend List Removed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallCreated(Core core, Call call) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Call Created");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVersionUpdateCheckResultReceived(Core core, VersionUpdateCheckResult
                    versionUpdateCheckResult, String s, String s1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Version Update Check ResultReceived");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChatRoomStateChanged(Core core, ChatRoom chatRoom, ChatRoom.State state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On Chat Room State Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onQrcodeFound(Core core, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On QR Code Found");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEcCalibrationResult(Core core, EcCalibratorStatus ecCalibratorStatus,
                                              int i) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On EC Calibration Result");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEcCalibrationAudioInit(Core core) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On EC Calibration Audio Init");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEcCalibrationAudioUninit(Core core) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Core listener - On EC Calibration Audio Uninit");
            }

        };
    }

    private void startIterateTimer() {
        cancelIterateTimer();
        mIterateTimer = new Timer();
        mIterateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mCore != null) mCore.iterate();
            }
        }, 0, TIME_ITERATE);
    }

    /**
     * Remove iterate timer.
     */
    private void cancelIterateTimer() {
        if (mIterateTimer != null) mIterateTimer.cancel();
        mIterateTimer = null;
    }

    private void enablePayloads() {
        PayloadType[] audioPayloads = mCore.getAudioPayloadTypes();

        for (int i = 0; i < audioPayloads.length; ++i) {
            PayloadType payloadType = audioPayloads[i];

            payloadType.enable(true);
        }

        mCore.setAudioPayloadTypes(audioPayloads);
    }
}
```

All the configurations and audio files are ok since they were working in the first implementation, but I guess I am doing something wrong on this class.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue, I was missing Core.start():

```
/**
 * Initiate Linphone library, set configuration.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void initLibrary() throws Exception {

    copyAssetsFromPackage();

    Factory.instance().setDebugMode(false, LIN_TAG);
    mCore = Factory.instance().createCore(
            mLinphoneConfigFile, mConfigFactoryFile, this);
    mCore.addListener(getCoreListener());
    mCore.start();
    mCore.enableIpv6(false);
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    mCore.setUserAgent(USER_AGENT, packageInfo.versionName);
    mCore.setRemoteRingbackTone(mRingSoundFile);
    mCore.setRing(mRingSoundFile);
    mCore.setRootCa(mRootCaFile);
    mCore.setPlayFile(mPauseSoundFile);
    mCore.setNetworkReachable(true);
    mCore.enableEchoCancellation(true);
    mCore.enableEchoLimiter(true);
    mCore.enableAdaptiveRateControl(true);
    mCore.clearAllAuthInfo();
    mCore.clearProxyConfig();

    enablePayloads();

    startIterateTimer();

}
```

Comment: Code snippet added @ArbazAlam

Comment: @svprdga not quite related to ur question but I'm stuck with another problem. I'm using EasyLinphone demo. with my own server configuration, on the receiver end the callbis dropped after 30/32 seconds. any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry @SolaimanHossain ... no idea about what this is happening to you, I'm a newbie in VoIP related things :(

Comment: @svprdga when incoming call comes at You, is the call dropped on 30/32 seconds on your case ?

Comment: No @SolaimanHossain, I can maintain the call as long as I want.

Comment: @svprdga if u don't mind, can u please provide me your Skype id? I need to discuss with u regarding Linphone SDK.